# How to use Pandas to read csv files stored on a shared folder?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use Pandas to read files from a shared folder, `pd.read_csv('smb://10.12.50.3/folder/test.csv')`. It shows this error: File b'smb://10.12.50.3/folder/test.csv' does not exist

Comment: You are connecting to a windows shared drive from linux is it?

Comment: No, it can take valid urls too.

Comment: You should look at examples of how to connect to a samba server.

Comment: won't `pd.read_csv('//10.12.50.3/folder/test.csv')` just work?

Comment: What does connecting to that share in a filebrowser/terminal do?

Comment: @EdChum It won't if you're connecting from linux to windows. Needs to be through simba protocol.

Comment: @EdChum No - you need to specify a scheme... How does it know I don't mean http to get a file from a webserver or file to get a local file..? (or ftp or...)

Comment: @JohnGalt presumably passing a file handle to that csv to `read_csv` should then work

Comment: Which when you work out the correct string to use to open that file to get the handle... you can pass that string straight to `pd.read_csv` anyway... :)

Comment: The easier way is to mount the path to your linux box `/mnt/path/` -> `smb://10.12.50.3/` and then `read_csv('/mnt/path/folder/test.csv')`

Comment: `b'smb://10.12.50.3/folder/test.csv' -- from the error` why are you passing the filename in bytes?

Comment: @JohnGalt Passing the file path as bytes?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ -- I mean't in error log, -- for `pd.read_csv('smb://..csv')` in Python3  gives `OSError: File b'smb://..csv' does not exist` and in Python2 `OSError: File smb://..csv does not exist`.

Comment: @JohnGalt I am trying to connect a linux(ubuntu) shared folder from linux(ubuntu). I can access the folder and copy files, but I can't use Pandas to read those files

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error and fixed it by mounting the shared path and using the resulting URL, as Zero pointed out in his comment, so this answer just expands on that. First create a folder to mount to:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/shared
```

Mount it (possibly you'll have to install CIFS first):

```
sudo mount -t cifs user=USER,domain=DOMAIN, //10.12.50.3/ /mnt/shared
```

Possibly you'll have to add a version string if you get "operation not supported" error, like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs user=USER,domain=DOMAIN,vers-1.0 //10.12.50.3/ /mnt/shared
```

If mounting was successful and you can see the folder in your file explorer, loading the file should work like this:

```
pd.read_csv('/mnt/shared/folder/test.csv')
```